# Track magazine subscriptions with shopify

Tags: e-commerce, shopify

My client sells magazines. However, for cash-flow purposes they only take a payment once for one- and two-year subscriptions.

e.g. You buy "one year" at checkout, and for the next 12 months, the warehouse sends you magazines.

I've seen recurring order plugins for Shopify, but nothing that fits the bill. The ideal workflow would go something like:

- Customer buys 1-year subscription
- Customer's magazine shows on a pick-list every month for the next 12 months (the end of the subscription period)
- Cancelling a subscription triggers a partial refund

Is there anything in Shopify that does this, or will we need custom development?

Comment: can you share with us what you ended doing to solve this ? thanks !

Comment: It was all manual, I'm afraid. The client didn't want to pay for any custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify will handle the payment and refund scenarios. In addition you will need to keep track of subscribers. You can [create a simple App](http://docs.shopify.com/api) that maintains a database with the ability to query current subscribers, using [webhooks](http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/using-webhooks) to track purchases and refunds.